# SQL - Transpose Interval

Tags: sql, intervals, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to solve an SQL problem (even don't know if this is possible or not).
Let me try to explain.

We want to transpose "range" of records based on date (interval) in one table to another table where this range will be kept as FROM/TO structure.

As example, we have the following starting table structure:

```
ID DATE
100  11-08-2012
100  12-08-2012
100  13-08-2012
100  17-08-2012
100  18-08-2012
101  01-09-2012
...
```

and we want the following table as result:

```
ID   FROM_DATE   TO_DATE
100  11-08-2012  13-08-2012
100  17-08-2012  18-08-2012
...
```

Intervals are kept in FROM/TO fields and in the case of a single date interval, the same date is kept in both fields.

Is there any way to do this using SQL?

Comment: yes it is possible but how do you decide the interval of dates?  Meaning what is the criteria to move from `11-08-2012  13-08-2012` and then `17-08-2012  18-08-2012`?

Comment: By days. In our example, the first interval (11-13) stop when the next day is not the 'next expected day' (in this example, the next expected day is 14).

Comment: To be more explicit, we want consecutive days in interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this would be possible directly in a query.You'll need to write some code in a high level language or write a procedure for it.

In that case, you'll need to simply get the rows of particular ID, order them by the date(?) and get the first and last row of the result. You can now populate the `FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE` using this logic.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. I find a complex Stored Procs that can do the job. In summary, the trick is to keep the previous and next rows somewhere and with this information, we can handle interval correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bouzouki - Stored Procs are not needed as long as you have a database that supports ROW_NUMBER(), or better yet LEAD() and LAG(). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12001729/1012053).

Answer (score 2):

This is very doable using pure SQL (no procedures or user defined functions) with any database that supports ROW_NUMBER(). Here is a SQLSERVER 2008 implementation, with [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f84f2/3).

```
-- Create a virtual table with 2 rows that is used to convert a single row
-- into 2 rows when the range is only a single day
with events as (
  select 'start' event 
  union all 
  select 'stop' event
),
-- Sort the data by date, partioning by ID, and assign a row number
sorted_dates as ( 
  select id, 
         dt, 
         row_number() over(partition by id order by dt) sorted_rownum
    from t
),
-- Find the dates that begin and end the ranges. Assign new row numbers
-- so that the START and STOP row numbers are always consecutive.
-- Convert a date that both starts and ends the range into two rows.
pruned_dates as (
  select d1.id, 
         e.event, 
         d1.dt,
         row_number() over(partition by d1.id order by d1.sorted_rownum, e.event) pruned_rownum
    from sorted_dates d1
    -- Look for a previous date that is the same day or 1 day earlier
    left outer join sorted_dates d0
      on d1.id=d0.id
     and d1.sorted_rownum  = d0.sorted_rownum+1
     and datediff(d, d0.dt, d1.dt)<=1
    -- Look for a next date that is the same day or 1 day later.
    left outer join sorted_dates d2
      on d1.id=d2.id
     and d1.sorted_rownum = d2.sorted_rownum-1
     and datediff(d, d1.dt, d2.dt)<=1
    -- Identify the record as a START date if there does not exist a prior date
    -- that is the same date or 1 day earlier.
    -- Identify the record as a STOP date if there does not exist a subsequent
    -- date that is the same date or 1 day later.
    left outer join events e
      on (d0.id is null and e.event='start')
      or (d2.id is null and e.event='stop')
   -- Ignore records that have not been identified as START or STOP records.
   where e.event is not null
)
-- Pair the START and STOP records and report the results
select d1.id,
       d1.dt from_date,
       d2.dt to_date
  from pruned_dates d1
  join pruned_dates d2
    on d1.id=d2.id
   and d1.pruned_rownum = d2.pruned_rownum-1
 where d1.event='start'
;
```

The solution is simpler and more efficient with a database that supports LEAD() and LAG(). Here is a SqlServer 2012 implementation with [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f84f2/11).

```
-- Create a virtual table with 2 rows that is used to convert a single row
-- into 2 rows when the range is only a single day
with events as(
  select 'start' event
  union all
  select 'stop' event
),
-- Use LAG() to get the previous date and LEAD() to get the next date.
-- The previous and/or next date may not exist, or it may be more than 
-- one day away.
dates as(
  select id,
         dt,
         lag(dt,1,'01/01/1900')  over(partition by id order by dt) prev_dt,
         lead(dt,1,'12/31/9999') over(partition by id order by dt) next_dt
    from t
),
-- Discard rows where both the previous and next dates are <= 1 day away.
-- Identify the remaining rows as either START or STOP.
-- Convert any date that both starts and stops a range into 2 rows.
-- For each remaining row, use LEAD() to get the subsequent remaining row.
-- At this point there are valid rows that have START in FROM and STOP in TO,
-- but also invalid rows that have STOP in FROM and NULL or START in TO. But
-- the invalid rows are required for LEAD() to give the correct value.
pruned_dates as(
  select id,
         event,
         dt from_date,
         lead(dt,1) over(partition by id order by dt, event) to_date
    from dates d
    join events e
      on (e.event='start' and datediff(d,prev_dt,dt)>1)
      or (e.event='stop'  and datediff(d,dt,next_dt)>1)
)
-- Filter out the unwanted rows, preserving the rows with START in FROM
-- and STOP in TO.
select id,
       from_date,
       to_date
  from pruned_dates
 where event='start'
```

Comment: Really great answer! Can you provide a quick walk-trough the code, so that all of us can understand it more properly. Please.

Comment: @mtk - Added comments to the SQL code. Also removed an unnecessary condition from the 2nd query.

Comment: @ dbenham - Wow, nice answer. Sorry for this very late comment but never too late to thank you. Unfortunately, we only use SQL Server 2008 R2 but I will keep both 2008 and 2012 solutions in mind (and in files) for next time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You need to use nested queries.

If you will explain the logic for the date selection, I can try to give you a better example

For example:

```
SELECT A.ID, MIN(date) as FROM_DATE, max(date) as TO_DATE FROM ( select ID, DATE FROM sourceTable) group by A.id
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work as we can have several MIN values and several MAX values for the same ID:

Comment: than I didn't understand the logic for the date range. can you try and explain it more?

Comment: Ok, no problem. I will try to explain with more details. In my example, we have several interval for the ID = 100 (to be very specific, we have two interval, one from 11 to 13 and one from 17 to 18). If we use your code, we will have the MIN of all records where ID = 100 (in our example, we will have 11). And for the Max, we will have the MAX of all records where ID = 100 (we will have 18 in our example).

Comment: But in fact, we need to have the MIN of the first interval (11) and the MAX of the first interval (13), then the MIN of the second interval (17) and teh MAX of the second interval (18), and so on if we have others intervals for the same ID. The problem is to find how to "create" these virtual interval.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works, but it's a bit of a mess.

```
SELECT id, date1 AS 'StartDate', 
    MAX(CASE WHEN date < ISNULL(date2,'1/1/2050') THEN date END) AS 'EndDate'
FROM table1
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.date) AS rn1, t1.id AS 'id1', t1.date AS 'date1' 
        FROM table1 t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t2
            ON t1.id = t2.id AND DATEDIFF(dd,t1.date,t2.date) = -1
        WHERE t2.date IS NULL
        ) AS sub1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.date) AS rn2, t1.id AS 'id2', t1.date AS 'date2'
        FROM table1 t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t2
            ON t1.id = t2.id AND DATEDIFF(dd,t1.date,t2.date) = -1
        WHERE t2.date IS NULL
        ) AS sub2 ON id1 = id2 AND rn1 = rn2 - 1

    ) AS sub ON id=id1
GROUP BY id, date1
```

Basically I join the table to itself and get only the dates where there isn't a corresponding previous consecutive date.  This gives me the start dates of each range.  I then join that query to itself, but join on row number - 1 to offset the second date by one, so each start date is in a row with the next start date.  Finally, I find the max date for each start date that's less than the next start date.

Here's the code to create a test table.  You'll need to put some data in it:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [pk] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume SQL Server.

```
with 
    pairs(id,start,finish) as (
        select
            id1.Id as ID,id1.[Date] as start,id2.date as finish 
        from
            IdDate as id1 
            inner join IdDate id2 
            on id1.id=id2.id and DATEADD(DAY,1,id1.Date)=id2.date),
    starters(id,start) as (
        select
            pair1.id,pair1.start
        from
            pairs as pair1
        where
            pair1.start not in (select finish from pairs)),
    finishers(id,finish) as (
        select
            pair1.id,pair1.finish
        from 
            pairs as pair1
        where
            pair1.finish not in (select start from pairs))
select 
    s.id,s.start,finishers.finish 
from 
    starters as s, finishers 
where 
    finishers.finish > s.start and 
    (finishers.finish < (select MIN(start) from starters where start>s.start) or 
     (s.start=(select max(start) from starters) and 
      finishers.finish > (select MAX(start) from starters where start=s.start)))
```

Input

```
100 2012-08-11 00:00:00.000
100 2012-08-12 00:00:00.000
100 2012-08-13 00:00:00.000
100 2012-08-17 00:00:00.000
100 2012-08-18 00:00:00.000
100 2012-09-01 00:00:00.000
100 2012-09-02 00:00:00.000
100 2012-09-03 00:00:00.000
100 2012-09-04 00:00:00.000
100 2012-09-05 00:00:00.000
```

Output

```
id  start   finish
100 2012-08-11 00:00:00.000 2012-08-13 00:00:00.000
100 2012-08-17 00:00:00.000 2012-08-18 00:00:00.000
100 2012-09-01 00:00:00.000 2012-09-05 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Nice answer too. Again, sorry for this late comment. I will kept your code in my wallet. Thanks to sharing yourknowledge.